# Twitter cursor stuck in infinite loop

Tags: android, cursor, listener

i'm a newbie in java programming so please go easy on me.

I'm trying to access the twitter api using `cursor` and after adding just the `cursor` and fetchResults3(with everything else left untouched), which is to navigate between pages of the twitter `json response`, the app keeps going into an infinite loop. The `callback` is supposed to stop when its value is 0.

Below is the listener.

```
public interface ServiceListeners2 {
//For getting friends :  @GET("1.1/friends/list.json")
@GET("1.1/followers/list.json")
Call<FollowersResponseModel> list(@Query("user_id") long id, @Query("cursor") long cursor);
}
```

Below is the code for loading the data from json response (cursor is initialised as long cursor = -1 as global variable

```
    private List<TwitterFollowers> fetchResults2(Response<FollowersResponseModel> response) {
    FollowersResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    return responseModel.getResults();
}

    private long fetchResults3(Response<FollowersResponseModel> response) {
    FollowersResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    Log.e("lol",String.valueOf(responseModel.getNextCursor()));
    return responseModel.getNextCursor();
}

    private void loadTwitterFollowers() {
    MyTwitterApiClient myTwitterApiClient = new MyTwitterApiClient(twitterSession);
    do {
    myTwitterApiClient.getCustomTwitterService2().list(loggedUserTwitterId, cursor).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<FollowersResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FollowersResponseModel> call, Response<FollowersResponseModel> response) {
            Log.e("onResponse",response.toString());
            twitterFollowers = fetchResults2(response);
            getActivity().setTitle(String.valueOf(twitterFollowers.size())+ " Followers");
            cursor = fetchResults3(response);

            Log.e("onResponse","twitterfollowers:"+twitterFollowers.size());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FollowersResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("onFailure",t.toString());
        }

    });
    }
    while (cursor != 0);
}
```

Comment: probably `responseModel.getNextCursor()` never returns 0.

Comment: @VladMatvienko i tried showing the value in log but it never shows

Comment: ok, I see the problem. It is much bigger. You are trying to check `cursor` in cycle, and modify it asynchronously. You basically shouldn't do this.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I see, what should i do? Add a listener? sorry i'm not experienced enough